# Display window when Iframe changes/loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using this script that shows a little warning when a user clicks on a link:

```
 <script>
var disclaimer="This link is not our responsibility - click ok to continue"
iframe.onload=function() {
  var links = document.links;
  for (var i=0, n=links.length;i<n;i++) {
    links[i].onclick=function() { return confirm(disclaimer);}
  }
}
</script>
```

I have an iframe in the site, I want to trigger the same window when the user clicks on a link on the iframe. Is there a way to do it with plain javascript?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the `iframe`'s `src` attribute have matching protocol, domain and port as your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **parent** keyword to invoke the current window instead of the iframe window.

For example, (in the iframe)

```
parent.confirm(disclaimer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the [protocol, domain and port matches your page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can access your `iframe`'s document with the `contentDocument` property (which is the standard, but you may need to use `contentWindow.document` instead).

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
    iframeDocument;

if ('contentDocument' in iframe) {
    iframeDocument = contentDocument;
} else {
    iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
}
```